# How to write a custom View class based on a xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a xml layout with a RelativeLayout that holds 4-5 subviews. I want to have a custom View class based on this xml layout with a custom onclick listner.

I have tried with a custom class by extending RelativeLayout and by having a View as member. And in my constructor i'm inflating the layout and assigning it to my View member. But I want to have the class itself similar to my inflated view object.
(did I make any sense!!)

my current code is similar to below:

```
public class CustomItemView extends RelativeLayout {
  private Context context;
  private View itemView;

  public CustomItemView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      itemView = inflater.inflate(layout, null);                
  }

  public View getView() {
    return itemView;
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to achieve it is to extend `FrameLayout` and attach the inflated layout to oneself (`this`) in the constructor:

```
public class MyView extends FrameLayout {

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_view, this);
    }

    // Your view logic here
}
```

Then you can use your brand new view programatically:

```
MyView myView = new MyView(context);
```

Or in an XML layout:

```
<packageName.MyView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```